# Can Azure Table Storage Query with projection return just the projected columns and not include the PK and RK?

Tags: c#, azure

I am writing a web.api controller that queries an Azure Table Storage table with a projection and needs to return a json string of the projected columns.

The result returns the projection but it also includes for each entity the base properties PK, RK, Timestamp and eTag.

I want to return to the screen a json string with just the projected columns but because the base properties are included I have to go through the extra step of stripping the base properties from each entity before serializing to Json.

Is there a way for the query to just return the projected columns?

Here is my code returning a TableQuery:

```
class Poco:TableEntity{
   ... Col1
   ... Col2
}


var rangeQuery = new TableQuery<Poco>().Where(filter).Select(new List<string>
                  { "col1", "col2" });

var result = table.ExecuteQuery(rangeQuery).ToList();
```

Here is the same code returning a DynamicTableEntity:

```
class Poco{
   ... Col1
   ... Col2
}


var rangeQuery = new TableQuery();
rangeQuery.Where(filter).Select(new List<string>
                  { "col1", "col2" });

var result = table.ExecuteQuery(rangeQuery).ToList();
```

Each of these examples returns essentially the same thing but in inverted structures, the TableQuery returns a list of Poco elements but each element includes a "base" property the contains all the base properties.
The DynamicTableEntity returns a list of base properties elements where each element contains a "properties" property that contains an array of the projected columns.

Answer (score 7):

You could query a subset of entity properties by using a query of **DynamicTableEntity** and also **EntityResolver**, refer to [Query a subset of entity properties](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/#query-a-subset-of-entity-properties) for details.

And here is the sample code to get only *Name* and *School* from azure table.

```
namespace ProjectedQuery
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Parse the connection string and return a reference to the storage account.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

            // Create the table client.
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

            // Create the CloudTable object that represents the "stevens" table
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("steventable");

            // Construct the projectionQuery to get only "Name" and "School"
            TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity> projectionQuery = new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>().Select(
                new string[] { "Name", "School" });

            // Define an entiy resolver to work with the entity after retrieval
            EntityResolver<SimplePerson> resolver = (pk, rk, ts, props, etag) => new SimplePerson {
                Name = props["Name"].StringValue,
                School = props["School"].StringValue
            };


            foreach (SimplePerson projectedPerson in table.ExecuteQuery(projectionQuery, resolver, null, null))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", projectedPerson.Name, projectedPerson.School);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The very properties I want to retrive
    /// </summary>
    class SimplePerson
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string School { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The entity contains all the properties
    /// </summary>
    class PersonEntity:TableEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string School { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: ty for your reply. This still brings down the base properties. I am doing something similar but without using EntityResolver.  I create the Poco in the Select and use the Dynamic properties to retrieve the columns. Here is my code:  `var rangeQuery = new TableQuery();  
            rangeQuery.Where(filter).Select(new List<string> { "Age", "Nme"});  
            var result = table.ExecuteQuery(rangeQuery).ToList().Select(x => new Poco 
            {  
                Age= x.Properties["Age"].Int32Value,  
                Nme= x.Properties["Nme"].StringValue  
            });`

Comment: the key is to combine DynamicTableEntity and EntityResolver, as you could see the **SimplePerson** is a normal class and actually you could delete **PersonEntity**, it was unused in the code, so there is no base properties, just properties defined in **SimplePerson**.

Comment: Thanks, it's really not clear, and not user-friendly behaviour in TableQuery API.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the DynamicTableEntity directly to your business object by passing its "properties" property into Azure Table Storage Client SDK (> v8.0.0) `ConvertBack<T>` method. T here is the type of your business object.